# How to add BrowserSync with Angular 6?

Tags: angular-cli, browser-sync, angular-cli-v6

I am using Angular 6 to develop a new app.

Is it possible to add BrowserSync to `ng serve`? Given that `ng eject` is disabled in the Angular CLI

Comment: Angular CLI does live reload natively, without having to do anything. Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Reload is fine, however, the page reloads and scroll position is at the top. I want to be at the same scroll position as before the reload. It could be achieved by adding BrowserSync.